# Optain an ID-Token from Microsoft ADFS Server

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, adfs2.0

My system is running in a Citirx environment with a rich client. Now I want to make a request to an (Java) OAuth/OIDC resource server and need an OAuth access or ID token the get access to.

My question is whether I could get an ID token directly from the ADFS server with the logged-in Windows user (logged into a Windows AD domain) without having to authenticate myself again?

Get an ID-Token from Microsoft ADFS Server using Kerberos authentication

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.